# How much CO2 can I fit in a 0.5 L plastic bottle?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

Let's say I have a 50 lb CO2 tank which can probably contain about 1000 L of the gas at 122 atm. Suppose I want to use the tank to fill a 0.5 L plastic bottle which only has air in it.

We know that gases always assume the shape and volume of their container. If that is true then that would mean that I can transfer the whole 1000 L of CO2 into the plastic bottle.
What happens in reality is that the pressure in the 0.5 L would have to rise to about 244 thousand atm, so how do I know how much CO2 to put into that 0.5 L bottle before it would presumably explode?

Comment: The pressures will equilibrate at roughly 122 atm.  That means that it will contain 0.5 L of CO2 at  122 atm (~1800 psi), neglecting the air.

Comment: @ChetMiller "Most two liter bottles begin to fail at pressures around 1,034 kilopascals, or 150 pounds per square inch. " (source: https://education.seattlepi.com/much-pressure-can-two-liter-bottle-handle-6313.html)

Comment: At 122 atm the CO2 should mostly be a liquid unless the temperature is more than 31 C. CO2 would liquefy at 5.1 atm or about 72 psi.

Comment: See the comment of @Karsten Theis. What is the pressure tolerance of your bottle?

Comment: If the temperature is at a level where the CO2 is gaseous at 122 atm, I supposed that p1V1 = p2V2 was valid.
Then I calculated p2 from it and it turned out a value of 244000 atm at 0,5 L. Where did I go wrong?